# No avd and image device in sdk manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am just starting developing android and I have downloaded
android studio and Eclipse with ADT on my ubuntu 14.4, I am unable to add virtual device for testing my applications,

My sdk manager is not absolutely like others I see in the sites, the options, platforms and extras are few ! It looks like this:

tools:

--Android SDK Tools

--Android SDK Platform-tools

--Android SDK Build-tools

Android 4.4W(API 20):

--Sdk platform

Extras:

--Android Support Repository

All of them are installed and nothing remains to install.

I refresh the list and check "Force http...sorces to be fetched ..." But wont work :( and the list remains unchanged.

I even have downloaded android SDK without adty and android-studio But the same problem still remains

when I go to create a AVD, select a target, device and name, I give this error at the bottom of window:
No CPU/ABI system available in this target.

---

*****************Some commands which I have tried********************

mojtaba@mojtaba [04:07:27] [~]

-> % Programs/Android/android-studio/sdk/tools/android list targets

Available Android targets:

id: 1 or "android-20"

Name: Android 4.4W

Type: Platform

API level: 20

Revision: 1

Skins: WQVGA432, QVGA, WXGA800, WXGA720, WVGA800 (default), HVGA, WSVGA, WXGA800-7in, WQVGA400, WVGA854

Tag/ABIs : no ABIs

---

mojtaba@mojtaba [04:07:39] [~]

-> % Programs/Android/android-studio/sdk/tools/android -v create avd --name d1 --target 1

Valid ABIs: no ABIs.

Error: This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.

---

mojtaba@mojtaba [04:09:06] [~]

-> % Programs/Android/android-studio/sdk/tools/emulator

emulator: ERROR: You did not specify a virtual device name, and the system

directory could not be found.

If you are an Android SDK user, please use '@' or '-avd '
to start a given virtual device (see -help-avd for details).

Otherwise, follow the instructions in -help-disk-images to start the emulator

---

I know my problem is with my CPU/ABI, but don't know how to solve it.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check in your ../adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platforms and make sure you have system images for different API levels installed. AVD manager reads the CPU/ABI from here. Also specify the path to your SDK on windows->preferences->SDK.